# Paypal preapproval key validity

Tags: paypal

We are using Paypal pre-approval API on our site. According to this

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/

"Ending date cannot be later than one year from the starting date".

How can we implement pre-approval payments to be valid more than one year?

Is it possible? Is there necessary to request pre-approval key again after one year? Or is it possible to do automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You have to talk to PayPal about getting that limit lifted. From your link:

**Note: You must specify a value unless you have specific permission from PayPal to omit this value.**

If you omit this value then the preapproval will not expire. If you can't get approved for this feature then you will need to reauthorize every year, as currently there is no way to refresh a key.